# How Do I Get the Instantiated DataTemplate object for an item displayed in a ContentControl?

Tags: wpf

I have a ContentControl whose content is being set in a ViewModel through binding.  I have a couple things that I would like to programatically set on the view/template that is being applied to the data object.  If I understand it right, the "Template" property is for the ContentControl, not the actual Content of the ContentControl.  How would I access the actual view obejct when WPF creates it and applies it?  For the example below, I want to make an adjustment to the vw:InfoType1View or vw:InfoType2View object when it gets instantiated.

```
        <ContentControl Name="mainContentArea" Content="{Binding CurrentInfo}">
            <ContentControl.Resources>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:InfoType1}">
                        <vw:InfoType1View />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:InfoType2}">
                        <vw:InfoType2View />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ContentControl.Resources>
        </ContentControl>
```

Comment: Actually, I might have missunderstood the question. What kind of adjustments do you want to make the views?

Comment: In this instance I'm trying to use the MEFContainer to do dependency injection.  The main  thing I want to do is run container.SatisfyImportsOnce on the created view so that the view is able to do some other things that require access to the container.  As it is, since the WPF system made the view object, the [Import]s are not satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using the MVVM pattern? In this case, you really shouldn't be programmatically making changes to your view!

Anyhow, you could handle the Loaded event, or the LayoutUpdated event (hard to determine which you need without more code). You can then navigate the visual tree, using my [Linq-to-VisualTree](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/) for example, to navigate the elements in the view that was constructed - and make your changes.

Comment: I am using MVVM.  From my understanding, using the view's code-behind isn't necessarily bad if only affects the view.  Really, the main thing I want is for the class vw:InfoType1View (for example) to be able to instantiate a new view and attach it to the same DataContext that it has itself.  Is there a better way to do this?